# Systematic Symfony 4 lazy service loading or annotation?

Tags: php, symfony, lazy-loading

It's possible to [lazy-load](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) a service in Symfony, but:

1. Is it possible to make it the default way to load services
   without having to configure it for all service?
2. Is there a possibility to annotate a service for lazy-loading?

Comment: 1. No
2. What do you mean annotate a service for lazy-loading?

Comment: I think 1 means you want a defaulted configuration for lazy, then to opt-in other services to non-lazy. So, lazy by default.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the lazy loading. There are multiple ways you can solve this:

For one there is the [new Service Locator that was introduced in 3.3](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-service-locators). The [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/service_locators.html) explicitly says:

> Sometimes, a service needs access to several other services without being sure that all of them will actually be used. In those cases, you may want the instantiation of the services to be lazy. However, that's not possible using the explicit dependency injection since services are not all meant to be lazy (see Lazy Services).

The referenced article on [Lazy Service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/lazy_services.html) describes another way to solve this which requires an additional dependency `ocramius/proxy-manager` which will then make it possible to mark services as `lazy: true` in your DI config.

I don't know if I understand the first question correctly, but if you don't want to manually configure dependencies you can rely on the autowiring feature [that also received major changes in Symfony 3.3 and 3.4](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html). You can only make the autowring a default per configuration file, but using the [PSR-4 autodiscovery](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-psr-4-based-service-discovery) can basically autowire your whol src directory if you want to with some manual intervention, e.g. for parameters.

Comment: I believe this doesn't provide an answer. The question was: is it possible to make all services lazy by default (without an explicit "lazy" DI tag).

Comment: Using the `_defaults` should make this possible just like you can set services public/private by default you could set them lazy by default using the proxy manager.

Comment: Most likely no, I get the error 'The configuration key "lazy" cannot be used to define a default value'